# How to mock an IEnumerable<interface> type and pass it to constructor

Tags: c#, linq, unit-testing, moq, ienumerable

I got a class which looks like below

```
public interface ILocationProvider
{
    bool IsRequiredLocation (string type);
}

public class MyClass : IMyInterface
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<ILocationProvider> _locationProvider;
    public MyClass (ILocationProvider[] locationProvider)
    {
        _locationProvider = locationProvider;
    }
    public ILocationProvider ProvideRequireLocationObject(string type)
    {
        ILocationProvider location = _locationProvider.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsRequiredLocation(type));
        return location;
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to write some tests for it. But I stuck passing the `Mock<IEnumerable<ITransitReportCountryFlowProvider>>` to constructor. Below my test code

```
[TestClass]
public class TMyClassTest
{
    private Mock<IEnumerable<ILocationProvider>> _locationProvider = null;
    private IMyInterface _myClass = null;
    [TestInitialize]
    public void InitializeTest ()
    {
        _locationProvider = new Mock<IEnumerable<ILocationProvider>>();
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void ProvideRequireLocationObject_Test1()
    {
        //Given: I have type as 'PMI'
        string type = "PMI";
        //When: I call MyClass object
        _myClass = new MyClass(_locationProvider.Object); //wrong actual argument as the formal argument is an array of ILocationProvider
        //_locationProvider.Setup(x => x.IsRequiredCountryFlow(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(true); //how do I setup
        ILocationProvider result = _myClass.ProvideRequireLocationObject(type);
        //Then: I get a type of ILocationProvider in return
        Assert.IsTrue(result is ILocationProvider);
    }
}
```

**Problem 1:** The line `_myClass = new MyClass(_locationProvider.Object)` in above test class, as the constructor's formal argument is `ILocationProvider[]` so I cannot pass a mocking object of `Mock<IEnumerable<ILocationProvider>>`

**Problem 2:** If I change the line `private readonly IEnumerable<ILocationProvider> _locationProvider;` in above `MyClass` to `private readonly ILocationProvider[] _locationProvider;` I will not be able to mock it as because mock must be an interface or an abstract or non-sealed class.

**Problem 3:** How do I set up for `_locationProvider.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsRequiredLocation(type));` in my test method

**Problem 4:** How do I assert that my method `ProvideRequireLocationObject` is returning a type of `ILocationProvider`

Comment: Why are you trying to mock it at all? Just create an array and pass that into the constructor. What aspect of array behaviour do you think you want to fake out? It sounds like you need to think more about what you're actually trying to test... I would have tests where: a) there are no locations; b) there are multiple locations, only one of which is required for the type; c) there are multiple locations which are required for the type; d) there are multiple locations, but none of them is required for the type.

Comment: No need to mock this at all, just mock one or more `ILocationProvider`s, put it in an array and pass that.

Comment: “How do I assert that my method `ProvideRequireLocationObject` is returning a type of `ILocationProvider`” – you don’t. It’s guaranteed to return an object of that type because of its contract.

Comment: @poke I believe I got a clear view from Jon and yours comments. Yet about problem 4 I was wandering that  `FirstOrDefault` can return null if condition is not satisfied.

Comment: In that case, just add tests that check for `null`. But you don’t need the tests to verify the type. See my answer for an example of how you could test this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you don’t need to mock the collection. Collections (arrays or lists) are tested well enough to trust on their implementation. Since your constructor expects an array, you *need* to pass an array. And the simplest way to do that is to simply pass an array. There is no reason to mock this at all.

Changing the *implementation details* of the class you are testing (as suggested in problem 2) will not change anything on the testing surface. Unit tests should always be independent from the internal implementation details anyway.

> How do I assert that my method `ProvideRequireLocationObject` is returning a type of `ILocationProvider`

You don’t need to do that. The method has that return type, so the compiler will only accept an implementation where the method returns that type. You are guaranteed by the language that *if there is a return value*, then it’s of the `ILocationProvider` type. So you actually just need to check for `null`.

Taking your implementation, below is a possible way to test this. Note that you don’t actually need to mock this. You usually mock things when the actual implementation is too difficult to set up (e.g. has other dependencies) or when providing a testable implementation is too much work (e.g. an interface with lots of method but you only need one). In this case, I’m assuming that the `ILocationProvider` is easy to implement, so we’re going to create a test type for this:

```
[TestClass]
public class MyClassTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void ProvideRequireLocationObject_EmptyCollection()
    {
        // arrange
        var providers = new ILocationProvider[] {};
        var obj = new MyClass(providers);

        // act
        var result = obj.ProvideRequireLocationObject();

        // assert
        Assert.IsNull(result);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ProvideRequireLocationObject_NoRequiredLocation()
    {
        // arrange
        var providers = new ILocationProvider[] {
            new TestLocationProvider(false)
        };
        var obj = new MyClass(providers);

        // act
        var result = obj.ProvideRequireLocationObject();

        // assert
        Assert.IsNull(result);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ProvideRequireLocationObject_OneRequiredLocation()
    {
        // arrange
        var providers = new ILocationProvider[] {
            new TestLocationProvider(true)
        };
        var obj = new MyClass(providers);

        // act
        var result = obj.ProvideRequireLocationObject();

        // assert
        Assert.AreEqual(providers[0], result);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ProvideRequireLocationObject_OneRequiredLocationNotFirstInArray()
    {
        // arrange
        var providers = new ILocationProvider[] {
            new TestLocationProvider(false),
            new TestLocationProvider(true),
            new TestLocationProvider(false)
        };
        var obj = new MyClass(providers);

        // act
        var result = obj.ProvideRequireLocationObject();

        // assert
        Assert.AreEqual(providers[1], result);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ProvideRequireLocationObject_MultipleRequiredLocations()
    {
        // arrange
        var providers = new ILocationProvider[] {
            new TestLocationProvider(true),
            new TestLocationProvider(true),
            new TestLocationProvider(true)
        };
        var obj = new MyClass(providers);

        // act
        var result = obj.ProvideRequireLocationObject();

        // assert
        Assert.AreEqual(providers[0], result);
    }


    public class TestLocationProvider : ILocationProvider
    {
        public TestLocationProvider(bool isRequiredLocation)
        {
            IsRequiredLocation = isRequiredLocation;
        }
        public bool IsRequiredLocation { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

Of course, you could expand those tests as necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I believe are looking at it from the wrong angle. I think you don't need to mock the `IEnumerable` (`Mock<IEnumerable<ITransitReportCountryFlowProvider>>`) - `IEnumerable` has been testing front and back and besides you don't want to have to implement all its logic..

I think you should mock your own classes: `Mock<ITransitReportCountryFlowProvider>`

And pass a normal `IEnumerable` containing your mock in it

Something like:

```
[TestClass]
public class TMyClassTest
{
    private Mock<ILocationProvider> _locationProvider = null;
    private IEnumerable<ILocationProvider> _locationProviderCollection;
    private IMyInterface _myClass = null;
    [TestInitialize]
    public void InitializeTest ()
    {
        _locationProvider = new Mock<IEnumerable<ILocationProvider>>();
        _locationProviderCollection = new List<ILocationProvider> { _locationProvider };
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void ProvideRequireLocationObject_Test1()
    {
        //Given: I have type as 'PMI'
        string type = "PMI";
        //When: I call MyClass object
        _myClass = new MyClass(_locationProviderCollection); //wrong actual argument as the formal argument is an array of ILocationProvider

        .....
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear that *anything* needs to be mocked, to be honest. I suspect just using a simple, already-tested implementation of `ILocationProvider` would be simpler, assuming it's easy to use that. If not, `ILocationProvider` *could* be mocked... or the OP could just create a fake implementation.

Comment: @JonSkeet - I personally would pass a mock of the ILocationProvider - because it is foreign logic and I'd like to check if it was called, how many times, with what values..... according  to the logic of the class. And I personally love `Fakes` - so all mocking code is quite thin and nice compared to other things

Comment: I guess it depends on whether the OP really wants to check the interactions, or just whether it's getting the right result. My experience is that interaction testing tends to make tests more brittle and harder to read - in most cases it's fine to just test the results. (Imagine if this were a collection of strings, and you were trying to find the first one longer than 10 characters - would you go out of your way to mock string somehow?) But it's definitely a subjective matter.